# Geolocation on smartphone devices doesn't run

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, driving-directions

in my website I have to launch google maps for driving directions when I click on a button. I know the end point but I must communicate the starting point, that's my position, with geolocation.
I've a problem with geolocation on smartphone devices. 
This is my code:

`jQuery(window).load(function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        myLat=position.coords.latitude;
        myLng=position.coords.longitude;
        jQuery(".btn").attr("href", "http://www.google.it/maps?saddr="+myLat+","+myLng+"&daddr=44.000000,7.000000")};
    }); 
});`

It works well on pc, but on smartphone it doesn't run. An error occures. Should I write a different href for these devices? If so, how?? 
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it. 
I detect if I'm using mobile devices and for them I use this code

```
if( isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows()){
        jQuery(".btn").attr("href", "https://maps.google.com?saddr=Current+Location&daddr=44.000000,7.000000")
    }
```

Thank you for your support Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

Look here if it can help you in some way. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp